# Meteor is math.radians,math.degrees exist

Tags: meteor

Did Math functionality exist in meteor.If so Please help me how to convert degree to radians.I have to convert the Latitude and Longitude values from degrees to radians.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you want it on the server use Meteor.Methods

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.methods({
   radians: function (degrees) {
   return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
},
 degree : function(radians) {
   return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
  }   
 });
}
```

or on the client just use this.

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
   var convertRadians = function (degrees) {
      return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    };
   var convertDegrees = function (degrees) {
       return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
    };
}
```